Change hover and active text color in WooCommerce YITH Ajax Product Filter
I have a YITH ajax product filter on my page but there is no styling options. I have tried to search the plugin CSS but what I can find there it says hover text color to be white. This does not come from setting of buttons. The green color is my accent color.
Here is the page with the filter: https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/
So how can I change this color text to white when it is on hover or active:

This I found in the CSS when inspecting the site but I cannot find the place with this text so I can change it:
--yith-wcan-filters_colors_titles: rgb(8,120,10);
    --yith-wcan-filters_colors_background: rgb(255,255,255);
    --yith-wcan-filters_colors_accent: rgb(8,120,10);
    --yith-wcan-filters_colors_accent_r: 8;
    --yith-wcan-filters_colors_accent_g: 120;
    --yith-wcan-filters_colors_accent_b: 10;
    --yith-wcan-color_swatches_border_radius: 100%;
    --yith-wcan-color_swatches_size: 30px;
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_background: #FFFFFF;
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_background_hover: rgb(41,113,29);
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_background_active: rgb(41,113,29);
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_text: #434343;
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_text_hover: rgb(8,120,10);
    --yith-wcan-labels_style_text_active: rgb(8,120,10);
    --yith-wcan-anchors_style_text: #434343;
    --yith-wcan-anchors_style_text_hover: rgb(8,120,10);
    --yith-wcan-anchors_style_text_active: rgb(8,120,10);

Here is the inspect code:
<div class="filter-content">
        
    <ul class="filter-items filter-label  level-0">

        
<li class="filter-item label active level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1" role="button" data-term-id="1071" data-term-slug="142">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                142                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,144" role="button" data-term-id="1072" data-term-slug="144">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                144                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,145" role="button" data-term-id="1073" data-term-slug="145">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                145                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,164" role="button" data-term-id="1074" data-term-slug="164">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                164                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,1800" role="button" data-term-id="1069" data-term-slug="1800">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                1800                            </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,1800es" role="button" data-term-id="1070" data-term-slug="1800es">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                1800ES                          </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,240" role="button" data-term-id="1075" data-term-slug="240">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                240                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,740" role="button" data-term-id="1076" data-term-slug="740">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                740                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,900" role="button" data-term-id="1077" data-term-slug="900">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                900                         </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,amazon-2d" role="button" data-term-id="1066" data-term-slug="amazon-2d">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                Amazon 2D                           </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,amazon-4d" role="button" data-term-id="1067" data-term-slug="amazon-4d">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                Amazon 4D                           </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,amazon-kombi" role="button" data-term-id="1068" data-term-slug="amazon-kombi">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                Amazon Kombi                            </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,duett" role="button" data-term-id="1065" data-term-slug="duett">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                Duett                           </span>
            </a>

    </li>

<li class="filter-item label  level-0 label-below">
    <a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/webbutik/?yith_wcan=1&amp;product_cat=142,pv" role="button" data-term-id="1064" data-term-slug="pv">
        
                    <span class="term-label">
                PV                          </span>
            </a>

    </li>

        
    </ul><!-- .filter-items -->

            </div>

Have tried a couple of CSS but not working so guess I am not finding the right CSS class:
body .yith-wcan-labels .labels-style-text-hover
{
        color: #ffff !important;
}

.filter-item label
text_hover: {rgb(8,120,10);}
text_active: {rgb(8,120,10);}

.filter-content 
text_hover: {rgb(8,120,10);}
text_active: {rgb(8,120,10);}


The following will add the necessary inline CSS, to change the active and the hovering text color from green to white of YITH filter items:
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_yith_filter_inline_css', 90000);
function custom_yith_filter_inline_css() {
    echo '<style>
    .yith-wcan-filters .yith-wcan-filter .filter-items .filter-item.label:not(.with-image):not(.disabled):hover .term-label,
    .yith-wcan-filters .yith-wcan-filter .filter-items .filter-item.label.active:not(.with-image) .term-label{
        color:#ffffff !important
    }</style>';
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

